# Twoway binding in wasm

Tags: uno-platform

I'm testing the Uno platform and wasm.

I test a simple databinding where I have a username in a textbox after login ainst a webapi I update the property of the username to test the update of the gui from a binded property in the viewmodel.

xaml.

in the login button

```
        var result = await webApiClient.LoginUser(ViewModel.LoginModel);
        ViewModel.LoginModel.Email = result.Model.Name;
```

If I run the app under UWP it works, under wasm the text box don't update.

```
<Page
x:Class="DeviceExchange.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DeviceExchange"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ios="http://nventive.com/ios"
xmlns:wasm="http://nventive.com/wasm"
mc:Ignorable="d ios wasm">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Device Exchange 
 Portal" Margin="20" FontSize="30" />
     <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="username" Margin="3" 
 FontSize="15" />
     <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind LoginModel.Email, 
 Mode=TwoWay}" Background="White" />
     <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="username" Margin="3" 
 FontSize="15" />
     <PasswordBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Password="{x:Bind 
LoginModel.Password, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="White"/>
     <Button Margin="0,5" Click="LoginButton_Click" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="6" 
Grid.Column="1" x:Name="LoginButton" Content="Login" />
 </Grid>
 </Page>
```

Comment: Could you share the xaml code?

Comment: Have you validated that the API call works? If you add `Console.WriteLine(result.Model.Name)`, what do you see in the browser console?

Comment: Hi my console show this.mono_wasm_runtime_ready
mono.js:1 fail: Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement[0]
mono.js:1       The member event PointerEventHandler UIElement.PointerWheelChanged is not implemented in Uno.
mono.js:1 fail: Uno.UI.DataBinding.BindingPropertyHelper[0]
mono.js:1       The [ScrollViewer] property getter does not exist on type [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox]
mono.js:1 The Bindable attribute is missing and the type [Windows.UI.Xaml.UnsetValue] is not known by the MetadataProvider. 
 .....

Comment: Could you please report this with a simple reproduction app on GitHub? https://github.com/unoplatform/uno

Answer (score 0):

`{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay}` is not supported right now on Uno.
https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2587

You can, instead, write it this way as a work-around:

`Text="{Binding LoginModel.Email, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`